# "Stored Procedure has too many arguments specified" SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have built a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_orders_by_dates 
    @start_date datetime,
    @end_date datetime
AS
    SELECT
      order_id, 
      orders.customer_id, 
      customers.name,
      shippers.name,
      shipped_date
    FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
    INNER JOIN shippers ON orders.shipper_id = shippers.shipper_id
    WHERE shipped_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```

When I execute the procedure using:

```
EXECUTE sp_customer_city 'January 1, 2003', 'June 30, 2003'
```

I receive:

```
Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_customer_city, Line 0
Procedure or function sp_customer_city has too many arguments specified.
```

Have I not properly specified that this procedure can take two arguments?

Comment: enter correct date format and check

Comment: You tried with the right stored proc?                 sp_orders_by_dates 'January 1, 2003', 'June 30, 2003'

Comment: Thanks J. Yeah, totally missed that.

Comment: BTW it is a very bad practice to start stored procs with sp. Those are what system stored procs use and every time you run one, it first looks for asystem proc and if it finds one with thes ame name it runs it instead. If it doesn't it has wasted processing time looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling a different stored procedure than the procedure you show was built.  sp_customer_city has less than two arguments defined which is what the error message means.  Calling sp_orders_by_dates will work.

Comment: Lol, I totally missed this point.  It may just be a typo, but +1 for good eyes.

Comment: Ah. Wow. I was looking at it for 15 mins without a clue. Completely missed that.  Thanks for the help. Will accept answer in 7 mins. Cheers.

Comment: If you alredy modified a stored procedure and you still getting that error, should be because you've the same query opened in other tab ... shit happens :(